# What is going on in this proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cayley-hamilton

I am reading a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem [here](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Emadden/M7210fall2012/lec20121119-Cayley-Hamilton.pdf). For a rough outline of the proof, let $A$ be a matrix representing the endomorphism $\phi$ over  finitely-generated module $M$ with generators $m_1,...,m_n$. Now, we can regard $M$ as an $R[x]$-module by letting $x$ act as $\phi$.

This next part is where I am confused. They let $\mathfrak{m}$ the column vector whose entries are the $m_j$. Then, we get $(xI-A)\mathfrak{m}=0$, which I guess works by letting matrix multiplication be letting the elements in the matrix with coefficients in $R[x]$ act on the elements of $\mathfrak{m}$.

The next step multiplies both sides by the adjugate matrix to get $[\det(xI-A)]I\cdot\mathfrak{m}=0$, which then completes the proof, as we $p(\phi)=0$, where $p(x):=\det(xI-A)$.

I guess my real question is: what is actually going on? I've never seen matrices used this way; is this just a formal manipulation? But then it feels like multiplying by the adjugate matrix is "wrong". How do I know that the manipulation in $R[x]$ preserves the module action structure? I'm sorry for phrasing this poorly but I just have a feeling that something is off and I may not have it articulated it that well.

Comment: As you say, $M$ is an $R[x]$-module. What us happening here is that $M^n$ (considered as a space of column vectors) is a left-module for the ring $M_n(R[x])$ of $n$ by $n$ matrices over $R[x]$. Both $xI-A$ and its adjugate are elements of  $M_n(R[x])$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng It seems like this is a mistake in the proof: I don't think we want to look at $M^n,$ but rather think of elements of $M$ itself as coming from a surjection $R^n\to M$ (i.e., choosing a generating set $\{m_i\}$ of $M$). Otherwise, $\phi$ is not necessarily representable as a matrix, and moreover even if it were, it would be diagonal and there would be little reason to consider it as a matrix in the first place (we would simply be looking at multiplication by a scalar $r\in R$ on $M$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My previous answer made a false claim -- that we wanted to view $M$ as an $M_{n\times n}(R[x])$-module. In fact, this will not work in general: while given an endomorphism $\phi\in\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ and a generating set $\{m_1,\dots, m_n\}$ of $M$ we may produce a matrix $A_\phi\in M_{n\times n}(R)$ such that
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R^n @>A_\phi>> R^n \\
@V\pi VV @VV\pi V\\
M @>>\phi > M
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, it is not the case that in general a matrix $B\in M_{n\times n}(R)$ induces a well-defined endomorphism of $M.$ However, this doesn't mean we can't use the main idea that $(xI - A)^{\textrm{adj}}(xI -A) = \det(xI - A)I\in M_{n\times n}(R[x]),$ we just need to be careful.

First, let's choose our generating set $\{m_1,\dots, m_n\}$ of $M$ and our  matrix representation $A_\phi$ of $\phi$ with respect to this generating set. Explicitly, we have some collection of constants $r_{ij}\in R$ such that
$$
\phi(m_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n r_{ij} m_j.
$$
If we let $\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1,\quad i = j\\ 0,\quad i\neq j\end{cases}$ and we consider $M$ as an $R[x]$-module where $x$ acts on $M$ by $xm = \phi(m),$ then the previous equation is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{j}(x\delta_{ij} - a_{ij})m_j = 0.
$$

Observe that if we assemble the coefficients of the $m_j$ as we range over all $j$ and all $i$ into a matrix, we obtain
$$(x\delta_{ij} - a_{ij})_{ij} = xI - A_\phi.$$
Now we apply the adjugate trick. Write $(xI - A_\phi)^{\textrm{adj}} = (b_{ij})_{ij}.$ Then the fact that $(xI - A_\phi)^{\textrm{adj}}(xI - A_\phi)  = \det(xI - A_\phi) I$ means that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}(x\delta_{kj} - a_{kj}) = \det(xI - A_\phi)\delta_{ij}.
$$
Taking  our equation $0 = \sum_{j}(x\delta_{kj} - a_{kj})m_j$ and multiplying by $b_{ik},$ we have
$$
0 = \sum_j b_{ik}(x\delta_{kj} - a_{kj})m_j.
$$
Next we sum these equations over $k$:
\begin{align*}
0 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ik}(x\delta_{kj} - a_{kj})m_j\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}(x\delta_{kj} - a_{kj})m_j\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n\det(xI - A_\phi)\delta_{ij} m_j\\
&= \det(xI - A_\phi)m_i.
\end{align*}
This holds for any $i,$ so that $\det(xI - A_\phi) = p(x)$ acts on $M$ identically as zero; i.e., $p(\phi) : M\to M$ is zero.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @Vasting you're welcome! I should also note that there's another error in the proof which I didn't mention explicitly in my answer -- see my comment under the main question.

Comment: Was just reading through again. Could you explain why $B\mathbf{r}\in K$? It does not seem immediately clear to me.

Comment: @Vasting: The short answer is that each entry of $B\mathbf{r}$ is an $R$-linear combination of the components of $\mathbf{r}.$ Since $K$ is an $R$-submodule of $R^n$ and each component of $\mathbf{r}$ is in $K,$ the result follows. More explicitly, write $B = (b_{ij})$ with all $b_{ij}\in R.$ If $\mathbf{r} = (r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n)^T\in K^n$ then the $k$th component of $B\mathbf{r}\in R^n$ is $\sum_{i = 1}^nb_{ki}r_i.$ Then each $b_{ki}r_i\in K$ and the sum of elements in $K$ is again in $K,$ as $K$ is an $R$-submodule of $M.$ So each entry of $B\mathbf{r}$ is in $K,$ which proves the result.

Comment: I guess I am confused by why each $r_i$ has to be in $K$. For example, if $\mathbf{r}=(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)^T$, we can say that $r_1m_1+r_2m_2+\cdots+r_nm_n=0$. But why does this imply that $r_im_i=0$ for any $i$?

Comment: @Vasting Ah, you're right: in fact, it doesn't make sense to say each $r_i\in K,$ as $K\subseteq R^n,$ not $R.$ Something is off here, but I'm not 100% sure how to fix it at the moment. I'll try to return later and update this with a proper explanation!

Comment: @Vasting I'm not sure that the original approach of considering $M$ as an $M_{n\times n}(R[x])$-module is salvageable, so I've explained how to apply the adjugate trick without actually treating $M$ as a module over the matrix ring.